# Subtract two numbers without using arithmetic operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, subtraction

The problem that I am facing is :-

How does the logic of bitwise operators are working in the code below?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    while (y != 0)
    {
        int borrow = (~x) & y;
        x = x ^ y;
        y = borrow << 1;
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 29, y = 13;
    printf("\nx - y is %d", subtract(x, y));
    return 0;
}
```

How is the function subtract(x,y) is working?

Comment: "Debug" it using pen and paper. Write all down the numbers (as bits) on paper, and do all the operations (still using bits) one by one. And split complex operations (like e.g. `(~x) & y`) into the simplest parts (e.g. `int temp = ~x; int borrow = temp & y;`)

Comment: In a nutshell: first the `borrow` variable is set to identify the carry bits. Then, the xor does a (carry-less) addition/subtraction, which is the same in base 2. Then, the carries are taken care of in step 3. I'm wondering whether this works for ripple carries as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In binary,

```
 x   y  | x-y
--- ---   ---
 0   0  |  0
 0   1  |  1 (with a borrow)
 1   0  |  1
 1   1  |  0
```

which is to say

```
 x   y  |       x-y
--- ---   ---------------
 0   0  |  0 - ( 0 << 1 )
 0   1  |  1 - ( 1 << 1 )
 1   0  |  1 - ( 0 << 1 )   
 1   1  |  0 - ( 0 << 1 )
```

That means that

```
x - y
```

is equivalent to

```
( x ^ y ) - ( ( (~x) & y ) << 1 )
```

because the result of the subtraction can be given by `x ^ y`

```
 x   y  | x^y
--- ---   ---
 0   0  |  0
 0   1  |  1
 1   0  |  1
 1   1  |  0
```

and the amount to borrow can be given by `(~x) & y`

```
 x   y  | (~x) & y
--- ---   --------
 0   0  |     0
 0   1  |     1
 1   0  |     0
 1   1  |     0
```

Checking what happens on (positive and negative) overflow is left to the user.

Answer (score 1):

**Using recursive function**

```
int reduce(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    int value, carry;
    carry = ((~a) & b) << 1;
    value = a ^ b;
    return reduce(value,carry);
}
```

**Using while loop**

```
int reduce(int a, int b){
    while(b){
        int carry = ((~a) & b) << 1;
        a = a ^ b;
        b = carry;
    }
    return a;
}
```